Why didn't eclipses cause mass vision damage in historical societies?
We recently had an eclipse in the US and the accompanying warnings about potential vision damage from looking at the eclipse directly outside of the full totality.
What I'm wondering is how eclipses happened in the past without damaging every single person's vision. Obviously most historical societies ascribed a lot of significance to natural events like this, and in an era without modern distractions, with much more connection to the natural world, and without modern scientific explanations of what was happening, the sun suddenly disappearing during the day would probably be one of the craziest things you'd ever seen. Seems like you'd probably look at it.
Like how did everyone not just look directly at the eclipse? These events aren't particularly uncommon, you could reliably experience at least one every generation, so how was this not causing mass blindness?
Was there some sort of cultural taboo enforced about not looking at it? Was it common scientific knowledge? Did people just deal with the eye damage and get by as best they could?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

A very cursory Google search strongly suggests "Because it is painful to look at an eclipse"  Most people avoid pain.

@MCW My understanding of the problem is that your normal pain reflex are lessened during certain phases of the eclipse. Like you can look directly at the sun when normally your body would force you to squint. Also, a lot of sources I've seen warn that your eyes can be damaged without you realizing it:
"Since the retina doesn't have pain receptors, you won't typically feel any eye pain if you have solar retinopathy"

Please move that into the question and document the assertion. (I confess that I'm skeptical.)

Most of the people looking at eclipses would have been peasants, who are not important enough for contemporaries to write about.

I don't know that this is a question we can point to historical sources to answer. Just as a logical exercise though, consider the amount of people who were outside with the sun every day (pretty much everyone), and somehow knew to avoid staring at it long enough to cause eye damage. Then consider how truly rare an event an eclipse is for any one inhabited location. This map of future eclipses might help give you an idea. It should be pretty clear that, as a Darwinian matter, the former dwarfs the latter.

This German article claims that cases of eye damage have been reported since ancient times, and that 300 cases of serious and permanent eye damage were reported after an eclipse in 1912 in Germany.

This book has a few relevant details including an ancient Greek source that recommended looking at an eclipse as reflected on the surface of water. https://books.google.com/books?id=S3X1BwAAQBAJ

Add to @T.E.D.'s point that if you have not been warned in advance that one will happen, an eclipse is not all that noticeable until fairly close to totality, and the damage done by looking at the Sun is lowest then. The pre-Modern world didn't have endless media sources saying, "The Great American Eclipse will happen here and at this time and it is wonderful thing you gotta see. And, by the way, don't look at it -- we're afraid you might get hurt and sue." I think the answer is a mixture of media over hyping the (very real) danger today, and few people paying attention then.

Also, the availability of existing but inadequate eye protection. Sunglasses, tinted glass etc. that makes it possible today to look at the eclipse (i.e. shielding you from visible wavelengths), without actually protecting your eyes adequately (from the UV component).

Vision impairments are not uncommon and increase with age.  Would it be possible to notice an increase after an eclipse and also to attribute it to the eclipse?
